# How to convert string in hash to integer

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I have built a form tag and gotten values selected from a user. This is what I get:

```
params[:user_answer_ids] = {"170"=>["599"], "162"=>["561", "563", "565"], "160"=>["549", "550"]}
```

Now I want to convert all string in this hash to int, like:

```
params[:user_answer_ids] = {170=>[599], 162=>[561, 563, 565], 160=>[549, 550]}
```

I want to convert to int because I want to compare question and answer ids later. Currently I have to use `to_i` method when looping in a hash, so I want to know whether there is any way to convert all string to int at once.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could fake it...

```
h={"170"=>["599"], "162"=>["561", "563", "565"], "160"=>["549", "550"]}
h.default_proc = proc{|h,k| h.key?(k.to_s) ? h[k.to_s].map(&:to_i) : nil}
p h[162]
```

Leaves the data unchanged.

Comment: Shouldn't be best to just retrieve the key and if it's not `nil` convert it `to_i`?

Comment: I like it, with the data unchanged.